# How to run cron job only when making a get request & not everytime we start the server

Tags: cron, nestjs, scheduled-tasks, cron-task

I want the cron job to get triggered only when we make a get request, it does for the first time, but if I save it will re-run again.

The code does not run whenever the server starts or restarts but as soon as I hit that specefic endpoint, It will run every time the server re-starts.

```js
  startTime = new Date().getTime();
  numberOfMinutes = 10;
  @Cron(CronExpression.EVERY_MINUTE, {
    name: 'myJob',
  })
  async getParisAirQuality() {
    this.logger.verbose(`Getting paris air quality`);
    const result = await this.getCityAirQuality({
      latitude: '48.856613',
      longitude: '2.352222',
    });

    const airQuality = new this.airQualityModel({
      result,
      datetime: new Date().toLocaleString(),
    });
    await airQuality.save();

    this.closeJob();

    return {
      result: airQuality.result,
      datetime: new Date().toLocaleString(),
    };
  }

  closeJob() {
    const job = this.schedulerRegistry.getCronJob('myJob');

    const endTime = this.startTime + 1000 * 60 * Number(this.numberOfMinutes);

    if (job.lastDate().getTime() >= endTime) {
      job.stop();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Queue would probably be the best option for such thing. You add it to the queue on get request, and then it will be processed otherwise. Commander could also be an option.

https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/nest-commander